Condensed matter physics application to undesrstand physics of failure
does condensed matter physics provide any theoretical model which I can use to understand physics of failure pertinent to fatigue crack and intergranular corrosion  through simulation of dynamic microstructure evolution of nickel supper alloys at high temperature?

Does "physics of failure" mean "the physics of the mechanical failure of a metal part?" As in - when does a piece of metal under strain break? Maybe the meaning of this question is clear to someone else, but not to me.

The failure mode needs to be specified, and the question needs to make clear what existing resources (metallurgy textbooks, journal articles) have been checked and why they're inadequate. Wikipedia even has an article on the topic with references.

What are supper alloys?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superalloy

Professor Michael Marder's group at U Texas Austin studies crack propagation and failure as a condensed matter person.  I imagine many other people do as well.
